# Can't bundle install after cloning repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Here's my error when I bundle. What's the problem?

```
bundle install
rbenv: bundle: command not found

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.3.1

command -v ruby
/home/brian/.rbenv/shims/ruby

command -v bundle
/home/brian/.rbenv/shims/bundle

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

bundle -v
Bundler version 1.15.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Set correct ruby (rbenv) version `rbenv global 2.3.1`
2. And then `rbenv rehash` and then `bundle install`.

If that won't work I think you should reinstall bundler

1. Once again set correct ruby version `rbenv global 2.3.1`
2. `gem uninstall bundler`
3. `gem install bundler`
4. And then `rbenv rehash` and then `bundle install`.